# How to boot a laptop from a DVD?

Tags: installation, boot

Just got a Lenovo laptop with free DOS installed on it. I followed instructions on Ubuntu site and downloaded ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso file.

I did burn the same to a DVD and trying to boot which is not happening.

Any help regarding the same is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that the machine will not boot from the DVD or that the DVD boots but never starts Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the boot order and move the priority of booting from dvd to first. I think you can do it in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i did a boot on usb using pendrivelinux and started installing ubuntu on laptop, it is going like a song till now. Thanks for the great support